# Spelling Beelzebub II

Tags: word

Without sunlight, the only way I have left to tell when a new day beings is the release of the daily Spelling Beelzebub. Unfortunately, this time the pangram is only seven letters long. Does this eternal torment never end? Please help me find which letter corresponds to each color so I can finish this wretched puzzle once and for all.
[image: Spelling Bee II]
Words found in alphabetical order:

1. YRRGR
2. TYPG
3. OYOG
4. BTPOYRG

(Y=yellow, B=blue, P=purple, G=green, O=orange, T=teal, R=red)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words are:

> ADDED; PAGE; RARE; UPGRADE

So the letters are:

> red = D; orange = R; yellow = A; green = E; teal = P; blue = U; purple = G